# getting content-created-date of an excel file

Tags: c#, excel, file, datetime

My goal is to display the date of an excel file.
But :
If I download the file from the internet , automaitclly the creation date and modify date are set to current time and date.
I looked upon the file's properties , and found that in section 'Details' , under personal infomation , there is a section called 'Source' and there , it has a property called 
' Content Created ' with the original date file.

Is there a way to get it to a string ??

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Microsoft DSO OLE Document Properties Reader to get this.

```
DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass oleDocumentPropertiesClass = new DSOFile.OleDocumentPropertiesClass();
oleDocumentPropertiesClass.Open("C:\\My Documents\\MyExcelFile.xls");
MessageBox.Show(oleDocumentPropertiesClass.SummaryProperties.DateCreated.ToString());
```

The DSO file can be downloaded from http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/Q224/3/51.asp

Comment: this worked for me.
Please note that you have to add the DSO.dll and reference it to your project. Also , please note that this value can be null. 
Make sure to take that in mind .
thank jac @jac

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can get the property using `ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")` like this:

```
Sub GetCreationDate()
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")
End Sub
```

I haven't used c# with Excel though but the MSDN documentation has an example: [Workbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties Property (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Creation date - date is lower case

Comment: Not according to the MSDN page I linked.

Comment: Dim bidp For Each bidp In ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties If bidp.Name = "Creation date" Then MsgBox CStr(bidp.Value) End If Next                    The Name Value is but it appears yours will work as well, my apologies.

Comment: @Sorceri Maybe it depends on version, I ran your code sample and it works with `Creation date`, but so did the sample I provided with `Creation Date`. (Using Excel 2010). I tried `CrEaTION DAtE` too and that worked as well, so I guess it's case insensitive.

Comment: Thank you all for your help .
Now I am getting an error on this line :
Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties dp = book.BuiltinDocumentProperties;
The excepton is Invalid castException .
 Why ?

Comment: @subirshan I don't know, sorry. It might be that you need to do a cast. The example code from MSDN does that: `Office.DocumentProperties documentProperties1 = (Office.DocumentProperties)this.BuiltinDocumentProperties;`

Comment: @subirshan see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,  JPW should still have his answer marked for the points. Not this one.

```
Excel.Application eApp = null;
            Excel.Workbook eBook = null;
                eApp = new Excel.Application();

                eBook = eApp.Workbooks.Open(pathToFile, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                var docProp = eBook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date");
                System.DateTime dt = docProp.Value;
                MessageBox.Show(dt.ToLongTimeString());
```