# How to get "Content Created" of origin property? C# Winform

Tags: c#, file, properties

How do I get this property in c#?

[image: property screenshot]

How do I get the value of the property as an example?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Comment: updated my answer with code example.

Answer (score 0):

with the reference from [How to get Document Content Created Date using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776737/how-to-get-document-content-created-date-using-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top)

No need to use the file. Just use the built-in document properties:

```
 internal DateTime GetContentCreatedDate()
 {
        Word.Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        Office.DocumentProperties properties = (Office.DocumentProperties)doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
        return (DateTime)properties[Word.WdBuiltInProperty.wdPropertyTimeCreated].Value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this data for NEW Office File Formats (e.g.: .docx, .xlsx etc.).

New office file formats are essentially Zip files, with XML data inside.

The "Content Created" date is held in the XML file "`docProps\core.xml`" within the tag "`dcterms:created`".

An example might be:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml;

ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(file.OpenBinaryStream());
var stream = archive.GetEntry(@"docProps/core.xml").Open();
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    for (reader.MoveToContent(); reader.Read();)
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "dcterms:created")
        {
            stream.Close();
            return DateTime.Parse(reader.ReadElementString());
        }
}
```

I'm still looking into the old file formats, but [OpenMCDF](https://github.com/ironfede/openmcdf) is the way forward for those.